# Box-sizing Margins in Safari

Tags: css, safari, margin

Using this code, [JSFiddle.net/k7s6b](http://jsfiddle.net/k7s6b/), the top three buttons align perfectly with the bottom wide button in every modern browser except Safari (including Safari on iOS.)

The concept is simple: In order to fill 100% of the width with three thin buttons, each button is 33% wide, leaving 1% for the gaps on either side of the middle button.

However, in Safari, the 100% wide button is always at least one pixel wider than the combined thin buttons.

Any ideas, suggestions, etc. are greatly appreciated.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./">Thin 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Thin 2</a></li>
        <li class="last_in_list"><a href="./">Thin 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="wide_button">Wide</p>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS (not including Eric Meyer's CSS Reset):

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttons {
    margin: 15px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
}
    .buttons ul { list-style: none outside none; }
        .buttons ul li {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0.5% 0.5% 0;
            width: 33%;
        }
            .buttons ul li.last_in_list { margin-right: 0; }
            .buttons ul li a {
                background: #000;
                color: #fff;
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

        .wide_button {
            background: red;
            clear: both;
            color: #fff;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: Moreover, in older IEs you can get rounding up. And third button will overflow or even jump to the next line. Percent sizes are hard to make pixel-perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, hopefully I'm not the only one who has searched for hours, then finally posted a question, and a few minutes after posting...stumbled upon the answer.

The problem is ‘sub-pixel’ rounding discrepancies and ambiguity in the specification which leads to a lack of consistency between browsers.

My solution for this layout is simply to widen the gaps between the buttons (so that any discrepancy is not as obvious) and float the last button to the right.

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time posting this question.  Hopefully this answer will help make others aware of the current limitation in box-sizing support.